# BLOCKED thread while executing Oracle procedure from Java class

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I had encountered an issue while running a standalone Java application.

This application connects to a Oracle 10g database and executes a stored procedure which returns a cursor object. Issue is, after executing the procedure, control is not returning back to Java class.

Following is the code used.

```
    public String execStoredProcedure(){
        Connection l_Connection = null;
        CallableStatement l_CStatement = null;
        ResultSet l_ResultSet = null;            
        try{
            l_Connection1 = getConnection();
            l_CStatement = l_Connection.prepareCall("{call " + retrievestprName() + "(?,?)}");
            l_CStatement.registerOutParameter(2, -10);
            l_CStatement.setString(1, ApplicationProperties.loggedUser);
            this.m_Logger.debug("before");
            l_CStatement.execute();
            this.m_Logger.debug("after");
            l_ResultSet = (ResultSet)l_CStatement.getObject(2);
        }catch (SQLException se){
            //se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I had observed that the procedure is executing completely on db server and no issues found in AWR reports.

I am encountering this issue randomly and unable to trace the exact cause. Found a good article [here](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.in/2011/04/javanetsocketinputstreamsocketread0.html) for this scenario. Please help me to overcome this issue.

Thread dump taken during issue occurrence.

```
    bash-3.2$ jstack -F 3390
    Attaching to process ID 3390, please wait...
    Debugger attached successfully.
    Server compiler detected.
    JVM version is 20.65-b04
    Deadlock Detection:

    No deadlocks found.

    Thread t@27: (state = BLOCKED)
     - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=84, line=129 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive() @bci=25 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive() @bci=1 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket() @bci=48 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=33 (Compiled frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(byte[]) @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read() @bci=5 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1() @bci=6, line=978 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1() @bci=1, line=950 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive() @bci=54, line=434 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean) @bci=547, line=180 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.execute_for_rows(boolean) @bci=10, line=869 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout() @bci=316, line=1080 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal() @bci=100, line=2904 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute() @bci=19, line=2995 (Interpreted frame)
     - oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute() @bci=58, line=4119 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.staticimport.bulkimport.BulkImportOracleImpl.execStoredProcedure() @bci=453, line=299 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.staticimport.bulkimport.BulkImportOracleImpl.executeBulkInsert(java.lang.String, com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.main.gui.StatusMessages) @bci=514, line=207 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.schedulingimpl.main.DataImportImpl.doBulkImort(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) @bci=49, line=46 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.schedulingimpl.main.ScheduledImportImpl.doBulkImport(int, java.lang.String) @bci=77, line=697 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.schedulingimpl.main.ScheduledImportImpl.doImport(int, java.lang.String) @bci=118, line=582 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.schedulingimpl.main.ScheduledImportImpl.process() @bci=739, line=410 (Interpreted frame)
     - com.sdgsoftware.managedinterface.schedulingimpl.main.ScheduledImportImpl.run() @bci=1, line=282 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=680 (Interpreted frame)


    Thread t@2: (state = BLOCKED)


    Thread t@26: (state = IN_JAVA)
    Error occurred during stack walking:
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:78)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
            at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
            at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)


    Thread t@21: (state = BLOCKED)


    Thread t@20: (state = BLOCKED)
     - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=134 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=16, lne=171 (Interpreted frame)


    Thread t@19: (state = BLOCKED)
     - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
     - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=116 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: What is your procedure doing - just opening a cursor, or is it doing any DML first, which might be blocking at DB level, e.g. from another session having uncommitted changes?

Answer (score 0):

From that same link you posted, it recommends setting socket timeouts to avoid this problem:

> In order to prevent and reduce the impact of such instability of your service providers, the key solution is to implement proper timeout

You should do that.

You'll probably also want to change the behavior of your app so that less time is spent on the server with an open connection, causing this problem to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I would add the timeout. However, the issue is not getting the control back to Java class. This was raised with DBA and verified AWR reports but no issue was found at db level.

Comment: forget about AWR. In this case you should use session trace. Also if the procedure execution takes a lot of time you should use TCP keepalive. See https://rubyorchard.wordpress.com/2007/04/07/oracle-jdbc-connection-keepalive/. This has to be set on app level and also on OS kernel level.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The issue was resolved by restarting the Oracle instance, though the root cause of for the original issue was not found out.